# My Samsung Galaxy S Duos GT-S7582 does not start

Tags: boot, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

My phone GT-S7582 does not start when powered on it only displays Samsung GALAXY S DUOS GT-S7582 and also it does not enter in to the download mode.

Comment: anything that worked ?

Comment: Try using Kies3, it's good and install samsung's firmware update!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for the past two days, tried many things like pressing   Recovery mode(<kbd>vol up</kbd>+<kbd>power button</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>), wiping the cache clear, reseting into factory mode, etc.

- You should first [install Kies3](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) on your PC and try again to go into the Download Mode (<kbd>vol down</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>+<kbd>power button</kbd>).
- Then connect your phone to PC using USB cable. Oh, before that, you should write down your Phone model (**GT-S7582** and Serial Number which is an alphanumeric code, behind your phone after you remove your battery.)
- Then open Kies, go to `Tools` option, then `Firmware upgrade and initialization` and do as prompted in next few windows.
- The download will start. Please make sure you don't disconnect the USB cable and You should have 3 GB of free space in your C: drive (in case your OS is Windows)
- Everything will be rest and your phone will be as good as new. Use Google account's backup to restore apps and settings...